# Why are the symbols <% %> used in asp .net?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have a line:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lblID" runat="server" CssClass="tt" 
               Text='<%# Eval("theatername") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

can any one explain me ,what does this do?

Comment: Have you even tried google!

Comment: it has nothing to do with jquery y have u tagged jquery into it

Comment: polin, yes i tried google but couldnt find it..

Comment: Swarnajith, i removed jquery...as i dont know what the code is doing i kept jquery in tags

Comment: Have a look [<%: %>](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It is **`Data Binding Expression Syntax`**

It is used for Data-binding in an `.aspx` page.

`<%# %>` tags indicate where the information from a specific data source is to be placed in the `.aspx` page.

You can use it for:

1. Expressions  `<%# ( customer.First Name %>`
2. Collection   `<%# myArray %>`
3. Method Calls  `<%# GetBalance(custID) %>`

Refer over here: [Data binding essentials](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860#1a)

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net use `<%%>` to input some thing in html page to be processed ,

Example :

`<%DateTime.Now%>`
when you run the aspx page it will be processed like 5/12/2012 12:00:00 pm

Answer (score 0):

These are used for HTML encoding. Check the link below

[Reference Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) / Click to view